# Mobile touch behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I've built my site, every little detail is carefully planned and while it looks awesome on PC, `:hover` effects kind of breaks my site on mobile.

Basically all my links, buttons and anything else `hoverable` stays to hover state until clicked outside.

Is there a CSS way to deal with touch devices' events so that item goes to *"hover"* state only for very short time when "clicked" just for feedback or do I need some kind of library / plugin? Or do I need to program all clickable elements with jQuery?

Im currently using WordPress and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your CSS

```
    element:hover {...
```

to

```
    element:hover, element:active {...
```

the `:active` subclass is resposible for element's behaviour when it is being clicked